# Как правильно сделать сериализацию формы?

Tags: jquery, php

Добрый день, есть форма такой структуры:

```
<form action="" id="add-user">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit" name="save">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при сериализации формы с помощью jQuery:

```
var formData = $("#add-user").serialize();
```

передать $_POST['save']?

Это бы решило многие проблемы...

Заранее,спасибо, за ответы.

Comment: непонятно чего вы хотите. функция serialize не для того, чтобы POST передавать.

Comment: POST запрос я передаю с помощью Ajax запроса, а внутрь пихаю сериализированную форму...

Comment: в чем ваша проблема ? serialize возвращает string, добавьте к ней  "&save="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#add_user').on('button', 'click', function(){
$(this).closest('form').preventDefault(); //Предотвращаем выполнение функций, предусмотренных стандартным поведением формы;
var formData = $('#add_user input').serialize(); //Ваша переменная;
$.post('file.php', {save: formData});
});
```

Не забывайте, что serialize() требует наличия атрибута name у всех перебираемых элементов формы, в нашем случае, у  input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form').find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    var data = {};

    if($(this).attr('type').toLowerCase() != 'checkbox') {
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = this.value;
    }
    else {
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = this.checked;
    }
});
```

Наверно вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: ckeckbox, заменить на checkbox? =)

Comment: @Indev угу, спасибо)